# chrome.devtools.panels - ExtensionSidebarPane.setExpression() usage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Per the [Chrome devtools API docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels.html#method-ExtensionSidebarPane-setExpression), I can execute an expression in my ExtensionSidebarPane which returns an object:

```
sidebar.setExpression("(" + exampleFn.toString() + ")()");

var exampleFn = function () {
    var selectedEl = $0; //https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#0_-_4

    return selectedEl;        
};
```

This is an over-simplified example; but the end result is an object displayed in my ExtensionSidePanel which is interactive. However, this object is *always* collapsed.

Is there an API to display the object as expanded by default? (At least the top-level object, not necessarily any children)